# A jquery plugin that will open images,sqf,flv in a lightbox style

Tags: jquery, media, lightbox

does anyone know of a good stable jquery plugin that will support images,swf,flv that will pop up in a lightbox style type of window.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox - http://fancybox.net

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Colorbox http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/  just an Awesome Lightbox Plugin :) Here are some examples -> http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html